# Python how to shuffle an ordered list to make sequences of elements?

Tags: python, list, shuffle

For instance we have an ordered list:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

I want to reshuffle this array to form:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Currently I'm doing:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
n_unique_elements = 4
arrays_with_same_elements = np.array_split(a, 5)

for idx in range(n_unique_elements):
    final_list.append(list_similar_a[0][idx])
    final_list.append(list_similar_a[1][idx])
    final_list.append(list_similar_a[2][idx])
    final_list.append(list_similar_a[3][idx])
    final_list.append(list_similar_a[4][idx])
```

So the variable

```
final_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

There must a `pythonic` way of doing this. Perhaps a built-in function in `numpy`? What other different techniques come to your mind to solve this problem?

Comment: how about np.random.shuffle(a). (Frankly, this is the first result if you search for "python list shuffle"... )

Comment: @Magellan88 `np.random.shuffle(a)` does not preserve the order of elements in sequence. I need new array to be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...]`

Comment: Does the number of occurrences of each element always the same?

Comment: @GZ0 Yes. Each unique element's frequency are the same.

Comment: Is the frequency known beforehand or does it need to be calculated from the list?

Comment: @GZ0 they are known beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the key parameter in sort() method:
https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions
or
using set()

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
b = set(a)
final_list = list(b) * len(b)
```

Comment: This is very clever! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try it: (pure python without external lib)

```
STEP = 3
lst0 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
lst1 = []

for x in range(0, STEP):
    for y in range(0, len(lst0), STEP):
        lst1.append(lst0[y + x])
print(lst1)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

So, You can use numpy:

```
a.reshape([4,3]).T.flatten()
```

so the `.reshape()` puts it into a rectangualr martix, the `.T` switches rows and columns and the `.flatten()` puts it in a linear vector again

now you only need to come up with parameters for the reshape part e.g. `.reshape([step, repetition])`

Comment: Wow this is really neat technique. Thanks for explaining the answer as well.

Comment: yes, and sorry for misunderstanding you question at first... my bad

Answer (score 0):

If the frequency of each element is the same and is known beforehand, this solution would also work

```
FREQ = 3
output = a[::FREQ] * (len(a) // FREQ)
```

Another `numpy`-based solution is this:

```
FREQ = 3
output = a.reshape((-1, FREQ)).flatten(order='F')
```

The `order='F'` argument flattens the matrix by columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
    uniqueValues, occurCount = np.unique(a, return_counts=True) # uniqueValues is the array of unique elements of main list
                                                                #occurCount is array containing frequency of unique elements
    common_occur=min(occurCount)                                # get frequency of co-occurrance

    final_array=np.tile(uniqueValues,common_occur)              #get tiled output array
```